# How can I authenticate and authorize Angular get or post requests using AspNetCore 2.2?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity

I have setup an dotnet angular project and then implemented authentication as follows in the StartUp.cs file.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

    services.AddScoped<IPasswordHasher<CustomUser>, 
        PasswordHasherWithOldMembershipSupport<CustomUser>>();

    services.AddIdentity<CustomUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AuthenticationContext<CustomUser>>()
        .AddDefaultUI()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    var connection = configuration.GetConnection("Authentication");
    services.AddDbContext<AuthenticationContext<CustomUser>>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connection));

    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<AuthMessageSender.ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();


    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    ...
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
    ...
 }
```

IdentityHostingStartUp.cs file which runs upon startup to configure authentication.

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddAuthentication();
            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                // Lockout settings.
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings.
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            });

            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                // Cookie settings
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);

                options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
                options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Identity/Account/AccessDenied";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

I have a custom redirect in my angular code to go to the authenticate page if the user is not logged in.

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(http: HttpClient, @Inject('BASE_URL') baseUrl: string) {

    http.get<Boolean>(baseUrl + "api/Home/Status").subscribe((authenticated) => {
      if (!authenticated) {
        window.location.href = baseUrl + "/Identity/Account/Login";
      }
    });
  }
```

And finally, my HomeController code to check the authenticated status of the logged in user.

```
[HttpGet("[action]"), AllowAnonymous]
public Boolean Status()
{
    var user = _accessor.HttpContext.User;
    return User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

The Status(or any other called api controller actions) action always has a null user name, user claims, and IsAuthenticated always returns false even after logging in.

This is driving me up the wall. I have read as many post and tried as many options as I could find and nothing seems to work.

At some point, I noticed that the user name was filled as expected. I thought it was solved. However, since then it has stopped working even though I haven't changed anything and I can't solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when your Debug settings are set to EnableSSL unchecked. This would also become and issue if you were to deploy without SSL enabled. As soon as I enabled SSL as in the picture below the application identity cookie was included in the ajax requests.

[image]